# while execute procedure ERROR: ORA-01403: no data found

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I am trying to execute the following function in oracle 11g

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE EMAT_PROC_AD_USER_LOGIN
(USER_ID_IN IN VARCHAR2, PASSWORD_IN IN VARCHAR2,USER_ID_OUT OUT VARCHAR2)
IS
    chk boolean;
    TESTING VARCHAR2(200);

BEGIN

    SELECT USER_ID into TESTING FROM AD_USERMASTER WHERE USER_ID=USER_ID_IN and password=password_in; 
    if(testing=user_id_in)then
      testing:=user_id_out;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('hi');
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(user_id_out);
      chk:=true;
    end if;

    IF (USER_ID_IN is NULL AND PASSWORD_IN IS NULL) THEN
      TESTING:='Username AND Password Cannot Be Blank';
      USER_ID_OUT:=TESTING;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TESTING);

    ELSIF (USER_ID_IN is NULL OR PASSWORD_IN IS NULL) THEN
      TESTING:='USER ID OR PASSWORD Cannot Be Blank';
      USER_ID_OUT:=TESTING;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TESTING);

    ELSIF chk THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TESTING);

    ELSE 
      TESTING:='USER ID AND PASSWORD INCORRECT';
      USER_ID_OUT:=TESTING;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TESTING);
    END IF;

    Exception
      When NO_DATA_FOUND Then
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ERROR: '||sqlerrm);
      Raise;  -- To ensure if this is the error, you will set get no_data_found raised... 
END;
```

while execute this procedure in oracle 11g it shows an error 
Connecting to the database emat.

> ORA-01403: no data found ORA-06512: at "EMAT.EMAT_PROC_AD_USER_LOGIN",
>   line 39 ORA-06512: at line 9 ERROR: ORA-01403: no data found

Comment: What is the issue? Your query returns no data, thus raising the NO_DATA_FOUND you're having. What did you expect instead?

Comment: if i execute the above procedure parameter will be emat_proc_ad_user_login(null,null)        then user_id_out will be 'User id and password cannot be blank'                          or emat_proc_ad_user_login('sadmin','admin')    then user_id_out will be 'sadmin' (i.e select user_id from ad_usermaster table) or emat_proc_ad_user_login('jshdf','admin') then user_id_out will be 'password is incorrect' and vice versa 'user id incorrect'                                 Kindly fix the bug in my procedure

Comment: Your code has more than one issue. Please post the needed behaviour of this procedure against a meaningful set of test data to help people to improve your code.

Comment: i had ad_usermaster is the table it contains user_id=sadmin , password=admin        this procedure contains three parameters two input and one output emat_proc_ad_user_login(user_id_in in varchar2, password_in in varchar2, user_id_out in) i need the login validation in this procedure. the result will be return to user_id_out.(i.e user and password correct means user id will be return in user_id_out otherwise error message will be reflect in user_id_out)

Comment: I can suggest to avoid using select into, because it slows down the performance of your code, better use cursor instead.

Comment: @TheName: the procedures seems to query for, at most, a single resulting row, so a cursor makes not much sense. Also, why shoud a cursor be faster than a simple query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say you have this table:

```
create table AD_USERMASTER(USER_ID, password) as ( select 'userName', 'password' from dual)
```

and you want your procedure to behave like the following:

```
USER_ID_IN  PASSWORD_IN  USER_ID_OUT
null        null         'Username AND Password Cannot Be Blank'
null        'xx'         'USER ID OR PASSWORD Cannot Be Blank'
'aa'        null         'USER ID OR PASSWORD Cannot Be Blank'
'aa'        'xx'         'USER ID AND PASSWORD INCORRECT'
'userName'  'xx'         'USER ID AND PASSWORD INCORRECT'
'aa'        'password'   'USER ID AND PASSWORD INCORRECT'
'userName'  'password'   'userName'
```

This could be a way:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE EMAT_PROC_AD_USER_LOGIN
(USER_ID_IN IN VARCHAR2, PASSWORD_IN IN VARCHAR2,USER_ID_OUT OUT VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN
    case
        when USER_ID_IN is null AND PASSWORD_IN is null then 
            USER_ID_OUT := 'Username AND Password Cannot Be Blank';
        when USER_ID_IN is null OR PASSWORD_IN is null then
            USER_ID_OUT := 'USER ID OR PASSWORD Cannot Be Blank';
        else
            begin
                SELECT USER_ID
                into USER_ID_OUT
                FROM AD_USERMASTER
                WHERE USER_ID=USER_ID_IN
                  and password=password_in;
            exception
                when NO_DATA_FOUND then 
                    USER_ID_OUT := 'USER ID AND PASSWORD INCORRECT';
            end;
    end case;
end;
```

**test:**

```
SQL> declare
  2      vUserCheck varchar2(100);
  3  begin
  4      EMAT_PROC_AD_USER_LOGIN(null        ,null      , vUserCheck);
  5      dbms_output.put_line(null        || ' - ' || null       || ' - ' || vUserCheck);
  6      EMAT_PROC_AD_USER_LOGIN(null        ,'xx'      , vUserCheck);
  7      dbms_output.put_line(null        || ' - ' || 'xx'       || ' - ' || vUserCheck);
  8      EMAT_PROC_AD_USER_LOGIN('aa'        ,null      , vUserCheck);
  9      dbms_output.put_line('aa'        || ' - ' || null       || ' - ' || vUserCheck);
 10      EMAT_PROC_AD_USER_LOGIN('aa'        ,'xx'      , vUserCheck);
 11      dbms_output.put_line('aa'        || ' - ' || 'xx'       || ' - ' || vUserCheck);
 12      EMAT_PROC_AD_USER_LOGIN('userName'  ,'xx'      , vUserCheck);
 13      dbms_output.put_line('userName'  || ' - ' || 'xx'       || ' - ' || vUserCheck);
 14      EMAT_PROC_AD_USER_LOGIN('aa'        ,'password', vUserCheck);
 15      dbms_output.put_line('aa'        || ' - ' || 'password' || ' - ' || vUserCheck);
 16      EMAT_PROC_AD_USER_LOGIN('userName'  ,'password', vUserCheck);
 17      dbms_output.put_line('userName'  || ' - ' || 'password' || ' - ' || vUserCheck);
 18  end;
 19  /
-  - Username AND Password Cannot Be Blank
- xx - USER ID OR PASSWORD Cannot Be Blank
aa -  - USER ID OR PASSWORD Cannot Be Blank
aa - xx - USER ID AND PASSWORD INCORRECT
userName - xx - USER ID AND PASSWORD INCORRECT
aa - password - USER ID AND PASSWORD INCORRECT
userName - password - userName

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: very thanks its perfectly working, actually i was confused in code , yesterday i had tried in postgres its working fine, but i am new to oracle so totally struck.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want please describe it little more. It is simple that while executing the procedure `SELECT USER_ID into TESTING FROM AD_USERMASTER WHERE USER_ID=USER_ID_IN and password=password_` this Query does not get any data from table. so use a begin and exception block like

```
BEGIN

   SELECT USER_ID into TESTING FROM AD_USERMASTER WHERE USER_ID=USER_ID_IN and password=password_
   Exception
     When NO_DATA_FOUND Then
      Do you task;
```

it should be your procedure

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE EMAT_PROC_AD_USER_LOGIN (USER_ID_IN IN VARCHAR2, PASSWORD_IN IN VARCHAR2,USER_ID_OUT OUT VARCHAR2) IS 
 chk boolean; 
 TESTING VARCHAR2(200);
 BEGIN
  BEGIN
    SELECT USER_ID into TESTING FROM AD_USERMASTER WHERE USER_ID=USER_ID_IN 
    and password=password_in;
  EXCEPTION
    When no_data_found then
     TESTING:= 'No data to print';
  END;
    if(testing=user_id_in)then
      testing:=user_id_out;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('hi');
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(user_id_out);
      chk:=true;
    end if;

    IF (USER_ID_IN is NULL AND PASSWORD_IN IS NULL) THEN
      TESTING:='Username AND Password Cannot Be Blank';
      USER_ID_OUT:=TESTING;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TESTING);

    ELSIF (USER_ID_IN is NULL OR PASSWORD_IN IS NULL) THEN
      TESTING:='USER ID OR PASSWORD Cannot Be Blank';
      USER_ID_OUT:=TESTING;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TESTING);

    ELSIF chk THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TESTING);

    ELSE 
      TESTING:='USER ID AND PASSWORD INCORRECT';
      USER_ID_OUT:=TESTING;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TESTING);
    END IF;

    Exception
      When NO_DATA_FOUND Then
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ERROR: '||sqlerrm);
      Raise;  -- To ensure if this is the error, you will set get no_data_found raised... 


    END;
```

Comment: BEGIN
   SELECT USER_ID into TESTING FROM AD_USERMASTER WHERE USER_ID=USER_ID_IN and password=password_in;                                     
testing:=user_id_out;
dbms_output.put_line(testing);
   Exception
     When NO_DATA_FOUND Then
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ERROR: '||sqlerrm); raise

Comment: hmm that's what you should do

Comment: while i execute the procedure the variable testing is not show, it shows no data found.

Comment: in your code as the query is getting executed it is getting an exception and going to main exception block and the raise statement is executed. so u are not getting the print. m editing you procedure.

Comment: Your mentioned procedure is not working .....                             Error(14,5): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "IF" 
Error(21,5): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "IF" 
Error(44,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END"

Comment: @dineshdanny you have some other problem in your code please check it its a different issue its relate with your syntax thing.